# How to call ajax function until already run ajax not give a response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to call my ajax function until already run ajax not give a response.

Page is load on every sec and every sec ajax function call but I want to call ajax until already run ajax function is not response.

Can I store ajax function refresh rate so that after this my function load?

Below is my code:

```
function realtime_content()
{
    
var xmlhttp=false;
if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined')
    {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
if (xmlhttp) 
    {
    RTupdate_query = "RTajax=1&DB=" + DB + "" + groupQS + usergroupQS + "&adastats=" + adastats + "&SIPmonitorLINK=" + SIPmonitorLINK + "&IAXmonitorLINK=" + IAXmonitorLINK + "&usergroup=" + usergroup + "";

    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'demophp'); 
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    xmlhttp.send(RTupdate_query); 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        { 
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
            {
            document.getElementById("realtime_content").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    delete xmlhttp;
    }
}
```

This is page load function:

```
function refresh_display()
{
if ($start_count < 1)
    {
    realtime_content();
    }
$start_count++;
if (ar_seconds > 0)
    {
    document.getElementById("refresh_countdown").innerHTML = "" + ar_seconds + "";
    ar_seconds = (ar_seconds - 1);
    setTimeout("refresh_display()",1000);
    }
else
    {
    document.getElementById("refresh_countdown").innerHTML = "0"
    realtime_content();
    setTimeout("refresh_display()",1000);
    }
}
```

I added an Image In this image page AST_timeonVDADall_final.php calling many times at page load and going in pending time.

So I want to resolve this pending time, if page is in pending no request go to on this page AST_timeonVDADall_final.php.

When pending resolved then this page AST_timeonVDADall_final.php call again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `$.when()` . [Document Link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

> **Description**: Provides a way to execute callback functions based on one
>   or more objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous
>   events.

Example of multiple ajax call

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
  // a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively.
  // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]
  var data = a1[ 0 ] + a2[ 0 ]; // a1[ 0 ] = "Whip", a2[ 0 ] = " It"
  if ( /Whip It/.test( data ) ) {
    alert( "We got what we came for!" );
  }
});
```